# How I can display Log files,System.out.println(), In Android test?

Tags: android, logging, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I did search a lot but unfortunately couldn't get it to work.

Based on my search I found that I need to add following code into build.gradle file. However, Gradle seems doesn't recognize it and always says `Geadle DSL method not found: test()`

```
test  {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    testLogging.events("passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError")

    afterTest { desc, result ->
        println "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}
```

## Update

I can confirm above code or better than that following code is working fine if you create a test project and move all your test cases inside that instead of `src/test/java` and `src/androidTest/java` in main project. It's because you can apply `java` plugin in build.gradle file. However, It's not possible to use following code in any build.gradle file that `com.android.*` has been defined. Since these two libraries are not compatible :(

```
apply plugin: 'java'
evaluationDependsOn(':YOUR-LIB')

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }

    afterTest { desc, result ->
        println "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }

    forkEvery = 5
    maxParallelForks = java.lang.Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors() / 2
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    // Need Gradle to ignore classes that are inner class of Test classes but not actually Tests
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Test.class"
}
```

So, my question is does anyone's INVENTED any way to print out logs under `android` plugin?